# Daubechies wavelet transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any function in Matlab for Daubechies wavelet transform which takes a matrix as an argument. I can 't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for a function called fwt2. most people who make their own version of the fast wavelet transform in 2D (which is not that hard really) call it that. loads of hits.

you can try wavelab, rice wavelet toolbox and wavekit which all definitely have the code, and the docs, to help you along: 
 www-stat.stanford.edu/~wavelab 
 dsp.rice.edu/software/rice-wavelet-toolbox 
 www.math.rutgers.edu/~ojanen/wavekit

not sure what a daubechies wavelet transform is, but these are 2 daubechies filters:

```
>> %db1
>> h=[1 1]; g=h; g(2:2:end)=-g(2:2:end);
>> %db2
>> s3=sqrt(3);
>> h=[1+s3 3+s3 3-s3 1-s3]/4; g=reverse(h); g(2:2:end)=-g(2:2:end);
```

You can call fwt2 with one of these as the filter

Answer (score 1):

Google `matlab daubechies wavelet` gave me:

- Matlab's [`dbwavf` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/dbwavf.html) in the wavelet toolbox
- Example implementation in Matlab on the [Wikipedia page about Daubechies wavelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet).

Answer (score 1):

Type `doc` into the matlab command window, and then you have to type `daubechies` in the left page, and enter it, then you can see and find daubechies in matlab.